# objective-c iphone programming : points of interest mapview

Tags: iphone, dictionary, location

i want to get the current location from the point of interest in my iphone app.

I don't want just a street name or city, for exemples restaurants.

The location returns "McDonalds" can it be possible i heard about the google api but i 
understand nothing at all. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I follow you correctly. Do you want to search for some point of interest, say "McDonalds" and be able to display it on the map?

Comment: no i want to get location im in the mcdonalds and it return mcdonalds not the street.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a 3rd party address-to-GPS coordinate lookup (otherwise known as a geocode lookup).  MapKit only provides reverse geocoding (GPS coordinate to address lookup).

Comment: Yes providing the 3rd party framework doesn't use any private APIs.